# Can't define asp:label within an if statement? (Get message about duplicates)

Tags: asp.net, webforms

We need to change the resource key for a given condition on an asp label.  The code in the aspx file looks like this:

```
   <% if(someCriteria())
       { 
   %>
        <asp:Label ID="mylabel" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="key1"></asp:label>
   <% 
      } 
      else
      { 
    %>
        <asp:Label ID="mylabel" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="key2"></asp:label>   
     <%
       }
     %>
```

On my box this compiles fine but on our build server I get an ASPPARSE error stating the ID is already used by another control.
I suspect this is a warning raised to an error on a release build.  Is there a compiler flag I can set to quiet this, or another way to do the above?

Comment: Web Controls are instantiated before the render function is evaluated, not at the same time, hence the issue you're seeing.

Comment: Also, I suspect this doesn't compile on your machine, but rather, your machine is not executing the `.aspx` compile step. What happens when you access the page in your browser or run `aspnet_compiler.exe` yourself?

Comment: The designer doesn't compile this code anyways. Simply put it in codebehind and use an if to set the myLabel.Attribites["meta:resourcekey"] to the value you need. You may be able to catch errors like this in publish though by setting the option to compile all resources as it goes and does some simple compilation with the designer.

Comment: Thanks all, the code-behind option sounds like the way to go.